# Camera Zoom unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I am using a script which zooms camera in and out, but I have added other cameras `POVs` to the game, so I am trying to make the script work for the current selected camera.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cameraZoomController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera cam;
    private float targetZoom;
    private float zoomFactor = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private float zoomLerpSpeed = 10;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
        targetZoom = cam.orthographicSize;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float scrollData;
        scrollData = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
        //debug.log(scrollData);

        targetZoom = targetZoom - scrollData * zoomFactor;
        targetZoom = Mathf.Clamp(targetZoom, 0f, 10f);
        cam.orthographicSize = Mathf.Lerp(cam.orthographicSize, targetZoom, Time.deltaTime * zoomLerpSpeed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script updates the current camera. Run it at `start()` and when switching game cameras.

```cs
void UpdateCurrent() => cam = Camera.allCameras[Camera.allCamerasCount - 1];
```

Comment: I have added this method and called it in start but nothing worked. @KiynL

Comment: Please show me the whole script. If it does not fit in the comment. Email at: Kian.tianxuan@gmail.com

Comment: Its same as above, and I only added the method u mentioned and called it in the start( ) thats all. I have sent you the script through mail.

Comment: You wrote `UpdateCurrent` before `cam = camera.main`. Make sure the cam does not change after executing the code.